# Alocação dinâmica de strings em um array

Tags: c, array, string, alocação

Estou com um problema para armazenar um vetor dinamicamente preciso guardar 10 nomes mas não estou sabendo como acessar esse dados pra impressão posterior segue minha tentativa

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define tam 3

int media(int *v1);
char *mais_alta(int *v1);
char *mais_baixa(int *v1);

void quantas_e_quais_mais_altas();
void quantas_e_quais_mais_baixas();
void imprime(int t, char *v1, int *v2);

int main() {
    int i;

    char *vet1 = (char *) malloc(tam * sizeof(char) + 1);
    int *vet2 = (int *) malloc(tam * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        printf("Nome % de altura %d\n", i, i);
        scanf("%s%d", &vet1[i], &vet2[i]);
    }

    imprime(tam, vet1, vet2);

    free(vet1);
    free(vet2);

    return 0;
}

void imprime(int t, char *v1, int *v2){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        printf("Nome:%s\nAltura:%d\n", v1[i], v2[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem vários erros aí, alguns não exatamente erros mas não é assim que se costuma fazer:

Os erros de sintaxe eu só arrumei, nem vou falar deles. Preste atenção em todos detalhes do código porque eu simplifiquei, melhorei a legibilidade e fiz de uma forma mais fácil de detectar erros.

Eu acho que para este caso a alocação dinâmica não é recomendada, mas talvez esteja querendo exercitar e usar algo diferente no futuro, mas saiba que este caso não é assim que se costuma fazer.

Você tem que passar os vetores para a função, na forma usada já deve dar os tamanhos já que tem ele de forma global disponível, se não tivesse teria alguma diferença, não vou complicar o que não precisa. Note que eu eu passei um vetor de `char *`, porque antes está passando só o `char *`. O `char *` é a *string*, não é um vetor de *strings*, por isso na hora de declarar eu o fiz mudando para que aloque um vetor de *strings*.

Tive que fazer a alocação de cada *string*, novamente não misture um vetor de caracteres que é a *string* com um vetor de *strings*, que no fundo é um vetor de vetores de caracteres, por isso tem dois ponteiros na declaração da variável `vet1` (podia ter usado nomes melhores).

Separei a leitura porque esta forma gera muita confusão.

Não esqueci de liberar a memória dessas *strings*.

Obviamente tem maneiras de melhorar mais.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define TAM 3

void imprime(char *v1[TAM], int v2[TAM]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) printf("Nome:%s\nAltura:%d\n", v1[i], v2[i]);
}
int main() {
    char **vet1 = malloc(TAM);
    int *vet2 = malloc(TAM * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        printf("Nome %d de altura %d\n", i, i);
        vet1[i] = malloc(21);
        scanf("%20s", vet1[i]);
        scanf("%d", &vet2[i]);
    }
    imprime(vet1, vet2);
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) free(vet1[i]);
    free(vet1);
    free(vet2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mGEHUx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/AllocationStringc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/String.c).

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero estou começando estrutura de dados agora e estou com algumas dificuldades sua resposta foi de grande ajuda!